# Считается ли алгоритм Дейкстры динамическим программированием?

Tags: алгоритм

Читаю в [википедии](http://bit.ly/1yd6U6U) про алгоритм Дейкстры. И у меня вопрос: считается ли этот алгоритм как динамическое программирование?

Answer (score 5):

Нет. В алгоритмах динамического программирования порядок вычисления промежуточных результатов фиксирован - здесь же вершины графа обходятся в неизвестном заранее порядке.

Зато алгоритм Дейкстры относится к классу "Жадных" алгоритмов.